# ReSharper set GoToNextHightlight to navigate to the errors first

Tags: resharper, resharper-6.0

ReSharper manages to find the errors without compiling but they don't seem to have higher priority than other hightlights . When I have a file with a lot of warnings (like unknown css class) I want to ignore, I can't use F12(go to next highlight) shortcut without going through all warnings. Of course I can use the scroll bar to go that error but it would be better to use keyboard shortcut. Any suggestions for this this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on your keymap:

- if using the R# keymap, press <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>F12</kbd>
- if using the VS keymap, press <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>PgDn</kbd>

This will invoke the "Go to next error" command, which ignores warnings, suggestions, etc.